# What is the difference between returning a response object and echo output?

Tags: http, httpresponse, slim

In Slim Framework routes, it's possible to return a response object or echo output using PHP's native `echo` function. What are the differences between these two methods?

Here are samples for each alternative:

**Returning response**

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) use ($app) {
    $response = $app->response;
    $response->setBody("Hello, " . $name);
    return $response;
});
```

**Echoing output**

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) use ($app) {
    echo "Hello, " . $name;
});
```

Both give me the same output:

> Hello, World

So why should I use the first one (`return $response`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://docs.slimframework.com/response/body/, there is no difference at all.

If you want to overwrite the output instead to appending to it you will have to use the `$response` object.
So you may want to use it for consistency reasons?

Comment: Using `$response object` seems to be the latest PSR standard and Slim3 is going for that which I find it a bit too complicated - http://www.slimframework.com/docs/

Comment: Also, when using the `$response` object, you can easily add headers to your response.

Comment: Without opening a can of worms, there is structured, well encapsulated, protocol compliant, safe and reliable `return $response`, and then there is `print`. As it turns out, `echo()`, in the *Slim* framework, is just as good. While true when inlining, it so happens to be a shortcut.